# USB GPIO board stops responding after high voltage relay with load is switched on

Tags: relay, gpio

I'm using [Numato 16 GPIO](http://numato.com/16-channel-usb-gpio-module-with-analog-inputs/) board to switch relays on 8 Channel Relay Module. Until no 220V load is connected to the relay all works fine and I can switch on/off relay using Serial port command to GPIO as many times as I want. But once I connect actual device (in my case pump) through the relay - relay switches on (or off) the device and GPIO board stops communicating through COM port. After reconnecting GPIO USB cable it works again one time. Is my micro bieng stung by arcs radiating? Do I need some sort of snubber?

Here is image of the current wiring:
[image: Wiring]

Previously I had GPIO Board feeding from USB, but was experiencing exactly same problem. Thought maybe it's not getting enough power from USB so rewired to use external 5V supply as it is now.

I wonder maybe somebody had similar problem or has an idea what can be done to solve it?

Comment: Not sure of this is related to your problem but the relay module is spec'ed to require 15-20 ma but the GPIO module can only source 8ma.

Comment: @DoxyLover: Can we have a look at your wiring layout? (Upload a decent photo or two.) There's a 'schematic insert' button on the editor toolbar if you want. Edit your question - don't post the additional information as comments. Welcome to StackExchange.

Comment: @transistor not my question. You meant Algis.

Comment: @DoxyLover: I have unit tests written for hundreds of switch on/off cycles using all 8 ports at the same and works fine. This behaviour starts appearing only when relay load is connected.

Comment: @transistor: updated question and added photo of the current wiring

Comment: @Algis: I see mains wiring to a solenoid running across your Numato. Turn the solenoid 180° and route the wiring the long way around the relay board. Twist the live and switched wires (around each other) to minimise mains interference. Regarding the build: I see low voltage, mains voltage and water all in the one box - **not good**. Even ignoring the water, you can't check any voltages without going past all the mains connectors on the left side. This looks like very poor layout and build.

Comment: @transistor: solenoids are 12V DC and not causing any problems when switched on switched... But I agree, I will have to change layout to separate voltages.

Comment: @Algis: OK, so it's only switching on the pumps. Are there connections between mains earth and Numato GND and, if so, what's the sequence? i.e., Are they daisy-chained (I'm not concerned about daisy-chaining all the mains connectors) or connected in star to one point.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it's an EMC problem rising from the surge current of your load (a motor pump).
If you supply the relay board with the same 5v as the Numato board, it's possible to have some return spike on the 5v that hangs the Numato CPU when the pump start. Try to put some ceramic capacitors (one 10uF and one 100nF) next to the 5V connector of the relay board.

Comment: I had Numato board feeding from USB and relay board from 5V suplly - was experiencing same problem...

Comment: Ok, then try (with this configuration) to separate the mains wires from the logic-level ones and test and re-test (ex: with same load on differents outputs).